# Picklist Not Visible In VF Page

Tags: visualforce, picklist

There is a picklist field on Contact object that I am displaying in a Visualforce page with a custom controller. However the drop down is not getting displayed for the user. 
The profile has access to the field and the picklist values are the same for all the Record types.
Also when the user goes to the standard Contact page layout, he is able to see the field and the drop down. 
The problem is only with the VF page.

```
        <tr>  
            <td>
              <apex:inputCheckbox label="Check box" value="{!d.CheckVal__c}"/>
             </td>

              <td>
                <apex:inputField label="Pick list " value="{!d.PickVal__c}"/>
               </td>
               </tr>
```

Class:

```
Contact dummyContact;

public Contact getDummyContact(){
     dummyContact = new Contact();
     return dummyContact;
 }
```

Please let me know what is the issue here? Is it related to the profile permissions or the VF page?

Comment: Check FLS and also check whether record type has access to this fields .

Comment: what is the VF variable `d` bound to in the controller

Comment: <apex:dataList value="{!dummyContact}" var="d" type="none"> 
table cellpadding="10px"> d is a var bound to the data list.

Comment: Yes this is likely related to a lack of **`write access`** on the field `PickVal__c`. As @MohithShrivastava mentioned it could also be related to `Record Type`.